# ElastiCache not utilizing read only replica

Tags: amazon-elasticache

I have a simple Redis ElastiCache cluster (cluster mode disabled) with a master node and a read only replica.

When throwing traffic at the server, i.e. from redis-benchmark, it seems all GET traffic goes only to the master node, while the RO replica gets zero GET traffic (cache hit/miss and GetTypeCommands are all 0).

Anyone has insights on why this is happening? I expected the traffic would be distributed between the two nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

older question but I am answering since I am just learning this myself...

I thought that the purpose was to balance the load between master and slave, but that is not the case. The slave exists so that it can be promoted to master if master fails for any reason.

further reading: https://redis.io/topics/replication

Comment: This is not true... From the docs you linked: `Replication can be used both for scalability, in order to have multiple slaves for read-only queries (for example, slow O(N) operations can be offloaded to slaves), or simply for improving data safety and high availability.`